# Docker ": You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/."

Tags: docker

Wondering if anyone had a problem with running a docker image that constantly casts ": You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/." at the end of the pipe.

tried:
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get -y autoremove
deleted old logs and backup archives.
mounted var/apt on another drive (TB drive, no space used).
"pruned" also...nothing happened

still same.

Drive has plenty of space (around 22GB) and yet, this shitty error bums me out because of 102MB. Anyone had this error? I don't know where to look anymore.

Thnx!

Comment: Do a `docker images` and see if you've got a bunch of images you don't need anymore.

Comment: Done that. Has not helped me at all. I think I need to figure how to resize the image itself (eventho it shows as it has free space)

Comment: Refer this [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178909/not-enough-space-in-var-cache-apt-archives)

Comment: Thank you. That one helped! I forgot to type back...Thnx!

Comment: i had the same issue even though i had 1.8 TB of free space. i solved it by adding shm_size of 1gb to when its running and building as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56655091/3208553